# How to install sshfs without sudo?

Tags: fuse, ninja, sshfs, meson-build

I'm trying to build `sshfs` on a cluster where I don't have `root` access.

Following [these](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.0/postlfs/sshfs.html) instructions I did:

1) Built and installed `ninja` and `meson`

2) Built `libfuse` with `meson --prefix=/cluster/home/user/fuse`

The problem comes when trying to install `libfuse` (`ninja install`), which requires root credentials. I get the following error:

> Running custom install script
>   '/cluster/home/user/fuse/libfuse/util/install_helper.sh
>   /cluster/home/user/fuse/etc /cluster/home/user/fuse/bin
>   /usr/lib/udev/rules.d' chown: changing ownership of
>   ‘/cluster/home/user/fuse/cluster/home/user/fuse/bin/fusermount3’:
>   Operation not permitted

How can I install `libfuse` to build `sshfs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fuse` simply requires suid. You can't avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem is that fusermount is available but the installed sshfs requires fusermount3. So basically once I compile if I execute `./sshfs remote@remote.com:folder ./mount_here` I get the error: `fuse: failed to exec fusermount3: No such file or directory`

What I have done is (in any folder in your $PATH) create a symbolic link as:

`ln -s /usr/bin/fusermount fusermount3`

and now my installed sshfs works. By time March 2022.

My problem is the same as the person asking in this post. I run on a cluster and I am not root so no able to install sshfs via apt-get