# makefile with prerequisite on another computer

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile on one computer, and I would like to use as a prerequisite a file on another computer that I can connect via ssh (but I am not an administrator). For instance, in this case, make print_hello runs only if the file on the other computer has changed since the last time print_hello ran.

```
print_hello: res@another_pc:/path_to_file
     echo "hello"
     touch print_hello
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Can't you just use `sshfs` to mount the remote file system locally at a known, fixed point?

Comment: I cannot as sshfs is not installed and I am not an administrator

Comment: This is not possible directly.  Make has no built-in concept of ssh (or any other remote storage access).  The only way to do it would be to write a rule that would ssh to the other system and either copy the file locally (preserving its timestamp) or else update a local file with the same timestamp as the remote file.

Comment: Note that even without admin privileges you can still build/install/use `sshfs` locally under your own home directory.

Comment: But here says you can't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152022/how-to-install-sshfs-without-sudo